# Speaker is treated as headphone

Tags: headphones, speakers

Tried both ubuntu 20.04 and 21.10. On a Huawei Matebook 13s 2021 laptop, speaker is treated as a headphone. When the headphone is plugged in, the speaker and the headphone are playing sound at the same time. When the headphone is removed, the speaker doesn't play sound. What is more interesting: when headphone is unplugged, and select "Headphones(unplugged)" as the output from PulseAudio Volume Control, the speaker works! So it looks like speaker is treated as a headphone. Is there a way to redirect/reconfigure it as the speaker? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of Huawei Matebooks have had this issue over the years. The solution is generally to add/edit a configuration file to your system.

Here’s how you can do the same:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Add a line to `sound.conf`:

   ```
   sudo sh -c "echo 'options snd-hda-intel model=alc255-acer,dell-headset-multi' >> /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf"
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** If the file does not already exist, it will be created.</sup>
3. Reset `alsa`:

   ```
   sudo alsactl restore
   ```

   Alternatively, a reboot will also work.

Sound should now work properly on your Matebook

Comment: Thank you for your help! It makes speaker works, but it's not a perfect solution. Every time plug in the headphone, the speaker and headphone plays together again, and after plug out it is not playing sound until do a `sudo alsactl restore` again.